# The Proof of $\cos\phi=\gamma$ Equation in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry, complex-numbers

In the Introductory Special Relativity book, by W. G. V. Rosser, page 182, Section 7.3, the author is defining the 4-vector methods using complex numbers. In his derivation, he writes the following equation (Equation 7.15):

$$\cos\phi=\gamma$$

> Equations (7.9) and (7.12) can be rewritten in the form
>   $$ X'_1 = X_1 \cos\phi + X_4 \sin\phi, \tag{7.13} $$
>   $$ X'_4 = -X_1 \sin\phi + X_4 \cos\phi, \tag{7.14} $$
>   where
>   $$ \cos\phi = \gamma, \tag{7.15} $$
>   $$ \begin{align}
>  \sin\phi &= (1-\cos^2\phi)^{1/2}
>  = \left(1-\frac{1}{1-v^2/c^2}\right)^{1/2} \\
>  &= \left(\frac{-v^2/c^2}{1-v^2/c^2}\right)^{1/2}
>  = \frac{i\gamma v}{c}.
>  \end{align} \tag{7.16} $$

The author deduced this equation, but I am not convinced. I would like to know please from where this equation came from?

Comment: It's a definition of some notation, not a theorem that needs to be proved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the author is using a convention where the rapidity, $\phi$, is imaginary. The reason for doing this is to ease your introduction to [hyperbolic trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function). The reason for doing this is because it makes boosts look exactly like rotation.

In 2-dimensions, a rotation matrix has the form
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
x' \\
y' \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \end{array}\right].$$
In special relativity, a 2-d boost looks like
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
ct' \\
x' \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\gamma & -\gamma \frac{v}{c} \\
-\gamma \frac{v}{c} & \gamma \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
ct \\
x \end{array}\right], \tag1$$
with $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}}$.

The usual definition given for rapidity $\phi$ that I've seen is to say that $\frac{v}{c}=\tanh\phi$. You can then use some hyperbolic trig identities to get that $\gamma = \cosh\phi$ and $\frac{\gamma v}{c} = \sinh\phi$. Dropping those into (1) you get the classic form of a hyperbolic rotation matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
ct' \\
x' \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cosh\phi & -\sinh\phi  \\
-\sinh\phi & \cosh\phi \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
ct \\
x \end{array}\right].\tag2$$
The determinant of the matrix in (2) is 1, as required for a "rotation", it just happens to preserve $x^2 - (ct)^2$ instead of Euclidean length.

You can make (2) look like an ordinary rotation matrix if you use the substitution $\phi\rightarrow i\phi$ and $ct \rightarrow -i x^4$ (may need to tweak the signs).

And that's what the book in question did.

Comment: FWIW, the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) "relates the circular functions and hyperbolic functions without explicitly using complex numbers".

Comment: My sincere congratulation for the your explanation.